# Create random database and convert it from numpy to pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I would like to create random database. in the database I want to create coordinaes so in the ed I can plot it, meaning, each point supppoose to have X and Y coordinate.

I have created data for one set of points but it is in numpy and I want it to be in pandas and I keep getting errors.

this is how I have created it:

```
#database 1
# defining the mean 
mu = 0.5
# defining the standard deviation  
sigma = 0.1

# The random module uses the seed value as a base  
# to generate a random number. If seed value is not  
# present, it takes the system’s current time. 
np.random.seed(0) 

# define the x co-ordinates 
X = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, (395, 1)) 

# define the y co-ordinates 
Y = np.random.normal(mu * 2, sigma * 3, (395, 1))

index=[X,Y]

##here I get all the errors 

df = pd.DataFrame({'X': X, 'Y': Y}, index=index)
```

The errro I recieved:

> Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional

I have also tried other methodes to make it dataframe but it didn't work and I believe it is something tiny that i'm missing.

My end goal is to create dataframe from those arrays.

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({'X': X, 'Y': Y})` wouldn't suffice?

Comment: @abhilb no, I get this error: ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({'X' : X, 'Y' : Y}, columns=list("XY"))` to set the column names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are calling `np.random.normal` is creating arrays of shape `(395, 1)`. That means that you are creating an array that contains 395 arrays of 1 element.

Example:

```
array([[0.67640523],
   [0.54001572],
   [0.5978738 ],
   [0.72408932],
   [0.6867558 ],
   [0.40227221],..])
```

This is what is breaking the pd.DataFrame call. So, to solve this, you need to pass the shape argument as (395) or simply 395 to create a one dimensional array.

```
#database 1
# defining the mean 
mu = 0.5
# defining the standard deviation  
sigma = 0.1

# The random module uses the seed value as a base  
# to generate a random number. If seed value is not  
# present, it takes the system’s current time. 
np.random.seed(0) 

# define the x co-ordinates 
X = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, (395)) 

# define the y co-ordinates 
Y = np.random.normal(mu * 2, sigma * 3, (395))

index=[X,Y]

##here I get all the errors 

df = pd.DataFrame({'X': X, 'Y': Y}, index=index)
```

I would also suggest you to remove the line `index=[X,Y]` and the `index` parameter while calling `pd.DataFrame` as it doesn't make any sense to me. You are setting as index the same values that you have at X and Y. The final code would be something like this:

```
#database 1
# defining the mean 
mu = 0.5
# defining the standard deviation  
sigma = 0.1

# The random module uses the seed value as a base  
# to generate a random number. If seed value is not  
# present, it takes the system’s current time. 
np.random.seed(0) 

# define the x co-ordinates 
X = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 395) 
print(X.shape)

# define the y co-ordinates 
Y = np.random.normal(mu * 2, sigma * 3, 395)
print(Y.shape)


##here I get all the errors 

df = pd.DataFrame({'X': X, 'Y': Y})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should replace 
`X = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, (395, 1))`  with  `X = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 395)` and `Y = np.random.normal(mu * 2, sigma * 3, (395, 1))` with `Y = np.random.normal(mu * 2, sigma * 3, 395)`.

In this way `X` and `Y` will be 1-dimensional: in fact let's check array shapes:

```
np.random.normal(mu, sigma, (395, 1)).shape
(395,1) #Hence this is a 2-dimensional vector

np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 395).shape
(395,) #this is a 1-dimensional vector
```

Comment: yes it worked, can you explain  the difference as i'm a beginner?

Comment: @Reut I edited my answer. In general you are giving the size parameter, and its lenght will correspond to the vector dimension. In particular there difference between (395,1) and (395,) is exactly the fact the the former implies the creation of a 2d array, while the latter generate 1d array

Answer (score 0):

Is this the plot you want?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list({'X': X, 'Y': Y}.items())) 
df.explode(1).apply(lambda x: x[1][0], axis=1).plot()
```